# how to add more claims to a jwt token in a custom authentication filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, jwt

I want to send more than just the username and roles using the authentication filter in springboot,
I'm using the user type inherited from userDetails from springboot security  whenever I try to manually get the name and add it as a claim I get a null exception. even though the method I use are tested and work outside of the filter.

code:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@Autowired
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

public CustomAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager){

    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}
String name;
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response ) throws AuthenticationException{

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");


    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,password);
    return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
}

@Override 
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException,ServletException{

User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
String name=userService.getName(user.getUsername()); //this method is tested and works but never here
Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("key".getBytes());
String access_token = JWT.create()
.withSubject(user.getUsername())
.withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+ 6 * 60*60*1000))
.withIssuer(request.getRequestURI().toString())
.withClaim("name", name)
.withClaim("roles", user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()))
.sign(algorithm);

String refresh_token = JWT.create()
.withSubject(user.getUsername())
.withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+ 8 * 60*60*1000))
.withIssuer(request.getRequestURI().toString())
.sign(algorithm);


Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<>();
tokens.put("access_token", access_token);
tokens.put("refresh_token", refresh_token);
response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), tokens);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the user or the userService that is null ? It's the first thing you need to look at when debugging NPEs

Comment: getName() returns a null pointer  even though it returns a name when I run it from the controller, it's what's confusing me. Am i not allowed to use services in the filter ?

Comment: Sorry didn't get it yet. So it's userService.getName(..) that returns null (and a NPE is thrown later in the execution of your program) or the userService is null and a NPE is thrown when you call userService.getName(..)? Can you show all the code of the filter?

Comment: it's the userService.getName() that returns the null and the npe is thrown entire filter is edited above